# One localhost on two systems

Tags: windows, ubuntu, xampp

I'm using Ubuntu and Windows 7 on the same computer,and have xampp installed on both and I want to have access to one local directory that is accessible to both Windows and Ubuntu. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: By "localhost directory", do you mean the local folder on the hard drive where the HTML/PHP/etc files are stored?

Comment: Yes, I want to load the same htdocs folder when I type in web browser localhost on windows or ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the webservers' document root (the directory that is served by the webserver, 'htdocs') on the Windows NTFS filesystem. You can serve files from there in Windows and Linux (Ubuntu can mount NTFS filesystems).

The disk should be mounted when you browse to them from the Files application. Command-line you can follow the guide on the [Ubuntu Documentation Center](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions):

Find the partition using `sudo blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Recovery" UUID="B23613F43613B875" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="38CE9483CE943AD8" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Data" UUID="519CB82E5888AD0F" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="00d7d951-2a35-40fd-8e5d-411bb824ff3b" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sda6: LABEL="Ubuntu" UUID="6044b1d0-208e-4ab3-850d-03a92e1516fc" TYPE="ext4"
```

Create the mountpoint:

```
sudo mkdir /media/Data
```

Change the `fstab` file with `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and add the following line:

```
UUID=519CB82E5888AD0F  /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0
```

(Change values where necessary)

Then mount the filesystem with:

```
sudo mount /media/Data
```

You can then find the data on the Windows partition under /media/Data, so configure your Xampp configuration to serve files from there.

Comment: When I type gksudo leafpad /etc/fstab and add at end of file UUID=519CB82E5888AD0F  /media/Data  ntfs-3g  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.utf8  0 0 I got this `Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files`
And if I change xampp to serve from window partition I have access forbiden on page.

Comment: That error is caused by Leafpad. It shouldn't affect the `/etc/fstab` file. You can check it of course with `more /etc/fstab`.

Comment: I got this after type more /etc/fstab `# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=AE7CA93F7CA902E7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

UUID=AE7CA93F7CA902E7  /media/Data  ntfs  defaults,windows_names,locale=en_US.ut
f8  0 0
`

Comment: Apart from the horrible formatting, you are using the same UUID for your Linux partition as for the Windows partition. You should use the UUID for the Windows partition as provided by `blkid`.

Comment: So I've changed to this `
UUID=29edd276-b53b-480b-a81e-1aaef106e217 / ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=AE7CA93F7CA902E7  /media/Data ntfs users,defaults 0 0 `
and still the same error.

Comment: The error is not a problem. The error is caused by Leafpad. Just ignore the error and try to mount the filesystem.

Comment: I can't mount `Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it whichcould be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.` 
How can kill proccess? I'm noob in Ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure it's not already mounted? Does it show up in the filemanager?

Comment: When I clicked on computer I have 3 disks from Windows and there is that disc which I want to mount is it correct and I dont have to mount it again?

Comment: No you don't, that's why I said in the original answer: *The disk should be mounted when you browse to them from the Files application*

Comment: So if I dont have to mount it again how can I get access to htdocs because when I change in xampp document root to: `DocumentRoot "/media/marcin/AE7CA93F7CA902E7/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "/media/marcin/AE7CA93F7CA902E7/xampp/htdocs">`
and type in browser localhost i got Access forbidden!

Comment: Check the xampp error logs and adjust permissions accordingly. Seems like a seperate question.

Comment: I dont have any errors in xampp logs but cant add permission to htdocs folder and subfiles even if i type chmod a+rwx /media/marcin/AE7CA93F7CA902E7/xampp/